# CUCM AXL API wrong SoapAction

Tags: spring, maven, soap, wsdl2java, cucm

I want to make SQL query to CUCM DB.  I generated Java classes from WSDL with Maven jaxb2 plugin, but Cisco AXL docs advice to use wsdl2java. I've got lot of Java classes with Req/Res endings (request and response as I understand). This is my code:

```
public class CUCMDatabaseConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{
    private String SOAP_ACTION = "CUCM:DB ver=10.5";    

    public void updateData(){
            String END_USERS_REQUEST = REQUEST,
                    AXLurl = "https://" + properties.getCurrentCUCM_IP() + ":8443/axl/";

            ExecuteSQLQueryReq sqlRequest = new ExecuteSQLQueryReq();
            sqlRequest.setSql(END_USERS_REQUEST);

            WebServiceTemplate template = getWebServiceTemplate();
            template.setMessageSender(NullHostnameVerifier.getMessageSender());
            ExecuteSQLQueryRes sqlResponse = (ExecuteSQLQueryRes) template
                    .marshalSendAndReceive(
                            AXLurl, 
                            sqlRequest,
                            new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                                    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                                    HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();

                                    //adding required headers
                                    connection.addRequestHeader( "SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
                                    connection.addRequestHeader("Authorization", autenString);
                                }
                           }
                    });             
            }
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get error:

`org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is https://IP:8443/axl/services/AXLAPIService and the WSA Action = CUCM:DB ver=10.5 executeSQLQueryReq`

So, as I see, problem is CUCM AXL service has **executeSQLQuery** method, but **not executeSQLQueryReq**.
How can I make Spring putting correct method in SoapAction? Or I need to use only wsdl2java?

---

**UPDATE**

When I was generating java classes, there was also .xsd schema in the directory. jaxb2 config pointed to WSDL file, however, I've got error `URI [src/main/resources/AXLAPI.wsdl] does not provide the scheme part.`, and It looks like plugin built classes from xsd schema, not wsdl. But this wsdl was original file downloaded from CUCM. What could be wrong?

Comment: Regarding your update. The problem is that "src/main/resources/AXLAPI.wsdl" is not a valid URI. The error "does not provide the scheme part" indicates that the "scheme" (e.g. "https") is missing. If the WSDL is on your local filesystem, use something like `file:///path/to/AXLAPI.wsdl`.

Comment: Thanks, "does not provide the scheme part" now gone and it prints `BUILD SUCCESS`, but generates no sources in target directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/learn/how-to/axl-java-sample-application.gsp) link on developers.cisco.com. This how-to advices to use AXLPort, a kind of wrapper for making SOAP request to CUCM. 
Looks to me, CUCM AXL SOAP interface is not the best choice to start working with Spring WS